# How can I rig a game where dice will always roll poorly?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, encounter-design, loaded-dice

I'm planning an encounter with the owner of a hotel casino who loads his dice, and for this encounter only I want my players to use special dice to roll poorly. If there is no website to purchase these from or a method to load my own dice, does anyone have an alternative suggestion to make this encounter have the desired effect?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and check out the [help centre](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) when you get a chance. In it's current form this question is too close to a "shopping" question which are off-topic here and will likely get closed. If you [edit] the question to ask for how to create loaded dice *in game* with mechanics instead of actual loaded dice, that will be a better kind of question for the site. Thanks for participating and happy gaming

Comment: I'm closing this as unclear, but it may also be off topic. (1) We don't handle recommendations for where to buy stuff. (2) The question never states what “the desired effect” is.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! I would find it easier to answer this question if you expanded on your goal. In particular, I presume the **characters** should find this a surprise, but do you also want this to be a surprise for the **players**? I'd also like to know how loaded or unfair you'd like the die rolls to be, and whether you're talking about the d20 rolls, all rolls, or some special dice for representing in-game gambling. (That is, one game being rigged isn't the same thing as fighting a luck mage who imposes general misfortune). Happy gaming!

Comment: @UKMonkey See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed. Thanks!

Comment: @doppelgreener you cool if I give the question an edit to make it work? I feel invested since I answered it and I think it has some rpg-stackworthy points.

Comment: @lightcat I think at this stage there's too little to go on in editing it into anything else. We cannot provide shopping recommendation and the querent has not stated their desired purpose. Whether they are looking to restore fun to their games versus some kind of revenge plot, for example, is going to mark a big difference in how this gets answered. (And it is probably the latter.) That isn't information we can glean from the little they have said though.

Comment: Good point... I don't get revenge plot at all from it (unless you meant inciting the PC's to revenge against the casino)... this doesn't read as contentional to me at all. It seemed a straightforward question at first, but I can see where we need clarification.

Comment: @doppelgreener Makes sense after I read some Meta posts.